# Parsing error: Missing '}' or object member name

Tags: php, json-ld

When validating my website json-ld tag using the google web console the following parsing error is emitted:

> Parsing error: Missing '}' or object member name

Here is my code, because when I tried to fix it google dropped from 10k impressions a day to 400 impressions

```
   <script type="application/ld+json">
    /* START TEST */
   {
     "@context" : "https://schema.org/",
     "@type" : "JobPosting",
     "title" : "{{ $post->title }}",
     "description" : "{{ $post->description }}",
    /* "description" : "<p>{{ \Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($post->description, 270) }}</p>", */
     "identifier": {
       "@type": "PropertyValue",
       "name": "{{ $post->company_name }}",
       "value": "{{ $post->id }}"
     },
     "datePosted" : "{{ $post->created_at }}",
     /*"validThrough" : "2021-08-18T00:00",*/
     "employmentType" : "CONTRACTOR",
     "hiringOrganization" : {
       "@type" : "Organization",
       "name" : "{{ $post->company_name }}",
       "sameAs" : "{{ $post->company_website }}",
       @if (isset($post->company) and !empty($post->company))
          <?php $attr = ['countryCode' => config('country.icode'), 'id' => $post->company->id]; ?>
"logo" : "{{ imgUrl($post->logo, 'medium') }}"
        @else
"logo" : "{{ imgUrl($post->logo, 'medium') }}"
        @endif
        
     },
     "jobLocation": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressLocality": "{{ $post->city->name }}"
      }
     },
 
  @if ($post->salary_min > 0 or $post->salary_max > 0)
       @if ($post->salary_min > 0)
         "baseSalary": {
            "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
            "currency": "USD",
            "value": {
              "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
              "value": {{$post->salary_max}},
              @if (!empty($post->salaryType))
              "unitText": "{{ $post->salaryType->name }}"
              @else {
              "unitText": "MONTH"  
              }
              @endif
            }
          }
       @else if ($post->salary_max > 0)
         "baseSalary": {
            "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
            "currency": "USD",
            "value": {
              "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
              "value": {{$post->salary_max}},
              @if (!empty($post->salaryType))
              "unitText": "{{ $post->salaryType->name }}"
              @else {
              "unitText": "MONTH"  
              }
              @endif
            }
          }
       @endif
     @endif
```

It worked before when I ignored that error.

Comment: a) No, this error should not be ignored. b) Why do you have JSON and PHP mixed like that? c) Please remove the chunks you have commented out as they are irrelevant.

Comment: Hey @LarsNielsen i know , this is how its built . Its a job posting website . i post jobs from here https://jobsmig.com/en/posts/create . the php codes are just to put the right values in the right fields ... such as job title , description , salary and more . Sorry witch chunks ??

Comment: Still bad mojo having raw JSON like this. Since you use PHP use a library that is able to wrap JSON or another structure that can be serialised to json. Then you will avoid erros like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at just the JSON and remove all your PHP and parse it through a JSON validator you will realise that the error is that you do not close the JSON block.
If you remove the PHP and replace `"value": {{$post->salary_max}},` with `"value": "{{$post->salary_max}}",` just so a JSON validator is able to eat it.

```json
{
    "@context" : "https://schema.org/",
    "@type" : "JobPosting",
    "title" : "{{ $post->title }}",
    "description" : "{{ $post->description }}",
    "identifier": {
        "@type": "PropertyValue",
        "name": "{{ $post->company_name }}",
        "value": "{{ $post->id }}"
    },
    "datePosted" : "{{ $post->created_at }}",
    "employmentType" : "CONTRACTOR",
    "hiringOrganization" : {
        "@type" : "Organization",
        "name" : "{{ $post->company_name }}",
        "sameAs" : "{{ $post->company_website }}",
        "logo" : "{{ imgUrl($post->logo, 'medium') }}"
    },
    "jobLocation": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "addressLocality": "{{ $post->city->name }}"
        }
    },
 
    "baseSalary": {
        "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": {
            "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
            "value": "{{$post->salary_max}}",
            "unitText": "{{ $post->salaryType->name }}"
        }
    }
```

You will get the error expecting `}` or `,` but got EOF.
The reason is that you are missing the closing `}` for the very first `{`.
The final JSON should look like this:

```json
{
    "@context" : "https://schema.org/",
    "@type" : "JobPosting",
    "title" : "{{ $post->title }}",
    "description" : "{{ $post->description }}",
    "identifier": {
        "@type": "PropertyValue",
        "name": "{{ $post->company_name }}",
        "value": "{{ $post->id }}"
    },
    "datePosted" : "{{ $post->created_at }}",
    "employmentType" : "CONTRACTOR",
    "hiringOrganization" : {
        "@type" : "Organization",
        "name" : "{{ $post->company_name }}",
        "sameAs" : "{{ $post->company_website }}",
        "logo" : "{{ imgUrl($post->logo, 'medium') }}"
    },
    "jobLocation": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "addressLocality": "{{ $post->city->name }}"
        }
    },
 
    "baseSalary": {
        "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": {
            "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
            "value": "{{$post->salary_max}}",
            "unitText": "{{ $post->salaryType->name }}"
        }
    }
}
```

So you code should be changed to include:

```
   
   {
     "@context" : "https://schema.org/",
     "@type" : "JobPosting",
     "title" : "{{ $post->title }}",
     "description" : "{{ $post->description }}",
    /* "description" : "<p>{{ \Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($post->description, 270) }}</p>", */
     "identifier": {
       "@type": "PropertyValue",
       "name": "{{ $post->company_name }}",
       "value": "{{ $post->id }}"
     },
     "datePosted" : "{{ $post->created_at }}",
     /*"validThrough" : "2021-08-18T00:00",*/
     "employmentType" : "CONTRACTOR",
     "hiringOrganization" : {
       "@type" : "Organization",
       "name" : "{{ $post->company_name }}",
       "sameAs" : "{{ $post->company_website }}",
       @if (isset($post->company) and !empty($post->company))
          <?php $attr = ['countryCode' => config('country.icode'), 'id' => $post->company->id]; ?>
"logo" : "{{ imgUrl($post->logo, 'medium') }}"
        @else
"logo" : "{{ imgUrl($post->logo, 'medium') }}"
        @endif
        
     },
     "jobLocation": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressLocality": "{{ $post->city->name }}"
      }
     },
 
  @if ($post->salary_min > 0 or $post->salary_max > 0)
       @if ($post->salary_min > 0)
         "baseSalary": {
            "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
            "currency": "USD",
            "value": {
              "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
              "value": {{$post->salary_max}},
              @if (!empty($post->salaryType))
              "unitText": "{{ $post->salaryType->name }}"
              @else {
              "unitText": "MONTH"  
              }
              @endif
            }
          }
       @else if ($post->salary_max > 0)
         "baseSalary": {
            "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
            "currency": "USD",
            "value": {
              "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
              "value": {{$post->salary_max}},
              @if (!empty($post->salaryType))
              "unitText": "{{ $post->salaryType->name }}"
              @else {
              "unitText": "MONTH"  
              }
              @endif
            }
          }
       @endif
     @endif 
}
```

Comment: Thanks am trying to validate and switch to your code . And it worked , i wish i knew you 2 days ago :(

Comment: Next time try the approach of stripping the PHP it helps a lot :) Please remember to mark the answer as an answer :)

Comment: yes am also trying to give you feedback , i don't see how .

Comment: on the top left of this answer you have an up vote and down vote. Below that is a check mark. That you use to mark the answer as a correct answer and then you can use the up vote button as well to give some kudos :)

Comment: i clicked on accepted this answer , the check mark. However i cant vote because am new :(  ... i will keep you in mind when i become an advanced user :) thanks alot sir

Comment: No problem :) Have a nice day